# Overwriting on an entry box in tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, opencv, tkinter

I'm trying to set up a user interface for the face recognition.

During the detection the details of the detected person automatically enters using text and entry widget of `tkinter`. When the next person comes in front of the webcam the entered data in the widget should be erased, which I'm not being able to do. It only works f i click the text box.

This is using `python 3.7` version in windows x64 and `sqlite3` from where the data is extracted :

```
cv2.putText(gray, str(profile[3]), (x,y+h+90), font, 1, color, stroke, cv2.LINE_AA)
Te = tk.Label(window, height=1, width=15)
Gender.trace('w',limitSizeGender)
Te = tk.Entry(window, textvar=Gender)
Te.grid(row = 6, column = 3)
Te.insert(tk.END, str(profile[3]))
```

This is a small part of the code.

Function `limitSizeGender` justs limits the size to 1 character.
`profile[3]` tells about the extraction of data from sqlite3.

'gray' is a variable used to display frame for face recognition

I expect the already existing data in the text box to erase automatically and the new details to fill in, is this possible using `sqlite` and `python`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  You can use `Gender.set("")` in your code to set the Gender variable to blank, or any other text string you need.

Comment: Hi! I tried doing this, but the text box gets cleared and not over written.

Comment: How about `Gender.set(str(profile[3]))`.